# Objeto Panel en visual studio c# - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy realizando una aplicación que consta de un solo Windows Forms y varios objetos Panel. La idea es que cuando se pulse una opción del programa muestre un panel u otro dependiendo de la opción elegida.

Los paneles los activo para visualizar con su método `Show()` y los escondo con `Hide()`. Los paneles para las opciones del programa tienen todos las mismas dimensiones.

Mi problema es que cuando elijo la primera vez una opción del programa desactiva el panel que hay en curso pero no visualizo el panel que activo con el método `show()`. No se si es posible mostrar y ocultar paneles las veces que se necesite.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si, se puede. Pero si no mostras tu codigo y donde tenes problemas no vamos a poder ayudarte mas. Usa el boton [edit] y describi todo en la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente hayas creado todos los paneles dentro del panel que estás ocultando, y por lo tanto, ocultas todos de golpe.

Prueba a poner antes del show()

```
nombreDelPanel.Parent = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres tener tu Formulario principal siempre activo y que tus Paneles se abran o se visualicen dentro del mismo formulario, con Paneles no es lo ideal; cambia a Formularios.
Para que tenga esa funcionalidad tu formulario principal tiene que ser **IsMDIContainer = true** esta opcion esta las propiedades del formulario.

Teniendo eso solo haces:

```
Formulario2 Form2 = new Formulario2;
Form2.MdiParent = this;
Form2.show();
```